# File data(Image, pdf) is not getting pushed into the MongoDB array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

**Whenever I upload the new file from the postman it overwrites existing file and save one and only uploaded file.**

*I have tried `document.push` method but it logs the error that "TypeError: documents.push is not a function" But when I log console.log(documents) it logs in an array. Am I doing something wrong?*

The multer function to handle file uploading:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./src/uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    var filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|pdf/;
    var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

    var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

    if (mimetype && extname) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }
    cb("Please upload valid file");
  },
}).array("documents");
```

The uploadDocument service file:

```
exports.uploadDocuments = async (id, documents, file) => {
  let files = documents.push(file);
  let document = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: { documents: files, registration_process_value: 99 } },
    { new: true }
  );
  return document;
};
```

The userController to upload the file:

```
exports.updateDocuments = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    check_user = await userService.getUser(req.data.id);
    if (!check_user) return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    if (check_user.registration_process_value >= 4) {
      let uploadDocument = await userService.uploadDocuments(
        check_user.id,
        check_user.documents,
        req.files
      );
      return res.status(200).json({ data: uploadDocument });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: error });
  }
});
```

The documents type is **Array** in the schema like following:

```
documents: {
      type: Array,
    }
```

`documents.push(file)` is returning a number (like if I `console.log(files)` after sending the request from the postman then it returns "files -> 2"). It is not pushing the actual data of the file.

Comment: Please also post your `User` schema.

Comment: Earlier it was [String] but currently it is `documents: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String,
    },`

Comment: Please add the full schema to your question.

Comment: I have updated the question. please go through it and guide me.

Comment: You should read the documentation about [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). The declaration of `documents` in your schema is invalid. Also, you can't (really) store image (or binary) data in MongoDB like that. Read [this](https://alexmarquardt.com/2017/03/02/trade-offs-to-consider-when-storing-binary-data-in-mongodb/) for more information.

Comment: Yes I am aware that declaration of documents in my schema is invalid(I have picked this from some online documents). I have also tried `documents:{type: Array}` but it is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you push a file into `documents` and store the new length of the array in `files`:

```
let files = documents.push(file);
```

Then you set the `documents` field to that array length:

```
  let document = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: { documents: files, registration_process_value: 99 } },
    { new: true }
  );
```

I assume that you want to store the actual array:

```
{ $set: { documents: documents, registration_process_value: 99 } }
```

Instead of using `$set` to replace the entire documents array, I would suggest using [`$push`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/):

```
{
  $set:  { registration_process_value: 99 },
  $push: { documents : file }
}
```

**EDIT**: if `file` is actually an array of file objects, instead of a single object, things change a bit.

If you still want to use `push`:

```
documents.push(...file);
```

With `$push`, you need to use [`$each`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-multiple-values-to-an-array):

```
{
  $push : { documents : { $each : file } }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it is working but minor problem here I want to store it as an array of objects not like array of array of objects `( [ [ { }, { } ] ] )`

Comment: If `file` is an array, things change. See my edit.